# Laravel custom unique validation with Rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I've searched for some questions related to my problem here and have applied them. But the result still not what I wanted for. Here are the references:

[Laravel conditional unique validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810009/laravel-conditional-unique-validation)

[Laravel | Unique validation where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211988/laravel-unique-validation-where-clause)

In my case, I want to validate the `name` field in the request to be unique when updating, **only if** the requested value **is different** from the previous stored `name` in the database. Here is my current code.

```
if(Request::method() == 'PUT') $rules = array_merge($rules, [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique('tags')->where(function ($q) use ($request) {

                $q->where('name', '!=', strtolower($request['name']));
            })
        ]
    ]);
```

In my database, I have some rows of data. The `name`s of those data are **product, event, and campaign**. When I want to update the **campaign** name with **product** in the request, the validation doesn't make this unique. It returns

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'product' for key 'tags_name_unique' (SQL: update `tags` set `name` = product, `tags`.`updated_at` = 2020-10-08 02:35:52 where `id` = 14)

I hope I explained it well. Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Edit #1:
My `tags` table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable()->unique();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Edit #2:

Here is my request payload from Postman in JSON.

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "name": "product",
    "description": "Descriptions"
}
```

Comment: Can you share migration file line of how you made unique constraint?

Comment: I've edited my question based on your feedback.

Comment: Does error happen on `NULL` value passed to DB or on non empty value or on both cases?

Comment: There are my requests in JSON that I am using in Postman. I am sure that the values are present (not null) before sent to the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do all this just to check unique validation on the same model.

Have you tried this?

```
if(Request::method() == 'PUT') $rules = array_merge($rules, [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:255',
            'unique:tags',
])
```

This should work just fine.
As mentioned in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)
If you are checking all conditions for the same model then you don't to check the where condition explicitly.